# When calling the metaclass bases, object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

When I try to use this one approach of singleton:

```
class Singleton(object):                                                     
    def __init__(self, name, bases, dict):                                   
        super(Singleton, self).__init__(name, bases, dict)                   
        self._instance = None                                                

    def __call__(self):                                                      
        if self._instance is None:                                           
            self._instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__()
        return self._instance                                                


class NewClass(object):      
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
```

I got an error:

> Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       object.**init**() takes no parameters

I'm not sure, am I correctly understand what the arguments are takes `__init__` method: `name, bases, dict`. And actually - where is my mistake/incomprehension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metaclasses derive from `type`, not `object`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. At least technically. The docs for [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)
 and [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass) state that it is allowed not to inherit from type (although not recommended). In Python2 it can be any callable.